# apparmor profile for a java application run run with java -jar

Tags: java, apparmor

I am working with `logstash` and it is unable to read some log files.
To be able to read, I think I have to add a profile in apparmor but am pretty lost at this point.

1. The app is run as:
   `java -jar ....`
   Do I have to add a profile for java or is there some other simpler way?
2. Will simply adding a single line like 
   `/path/to/mylogs r`
   work?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a systemd service that starts an application via `java -jar ...`.

As `aa-genprof` and AppArmor in general only works with file path and not PIDs and the jar files are not executables, it seems to me like one has to write a profile manually, maybe assisted by `aa-easyprof`, `aa-genprof` or `aa-logprof` for java.

The profile can then be enforced with e.g. the `AppArmorProfile=` directive in systemd.